# How to implement DRM in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, drm

I am using this react-native-video [this](https://github.com/24i/react-native-video) forked version of original react-native-video because it has a DRM support. I check their  DRM [doc](https://github.com/24i/react-native-video/blob/feature/ios-drm-support/DRM.md) too. But cannot get any success.
This is the example how I am trying to implement DRM. But cannot make video play. 
Its shows no any errors or warnings.

```
 <Video
        source={{
          uri:
            "https://media.axprod.net/TestVectors/v7-MultiDRM-SingleKey/Manifest_1080p.mpd"
        }}
        drm={{
          type: "widevine",
          licenseServer:
            "https://drm-widevine-licensing.axtest.net/AcquireLicense",
          headers: {
            "X-AxDRM-Message":
              "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJjb21fa2V5X2lkIjoiYjMzNjRlYjUtNTFmNi00YWUzLThjOTgtMzNjZWQ1ZTMxYzc4IiwibWVzc2FnZSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiZW50aXRsZW1lbnRfbWVzc2FnZSIsImZpcnN0X3BsYXlfZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6NjAsInBsYXlyZWFkeSI6eyJyZWFsX3RpbWVfZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6dHJ1ZX0sImtleXMiOlt7ImlkIjoiOWViNDA1MGQtZTQ0Yi00ODAyLTkzMmUtMjdkNzUwODNlMjY2IiwiZW5jcnlwdGVkX2tleSI6ImxLM09qSExZVzI0Y3Iya3RSNzRmbnc9PSJ9XX19.FAbIiPxX8BHi9RwfzD7Yn-wugU19ghrkBFKsaCPrZmU"
          }
        }}

        ref={ref => {
          this.player = ref;
        }}
        style={styles.backgroundVideo}
      />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<Video
source={{
    uri: 'https://media.axprod.net/TestVectors/v7-MultiDRM-SingleKey/Manifest_1080p.mpd',
    drm: {
        type: 'widevine',
        licenseServer: 'https://drm-widevine-licensing.axtest.net/AcquireLicense',
        headers: {
            'X-AxDRM-Message': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJjb21fa2V5X2lkIjoiYjMzNjRlYjUtNTFmNi00YWUzLThjOTgtMzNjZWQ1ZTMxYzc4IiwibWVzc2FnZSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiZW50aXRsZW1lbnRfbWVzc2FnZSIsImZpcnN0X3BsYXlfZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6NjAsInBsYXlyZWFkeSI6eyJyZWFsX3RpbWVfZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6dHJ1ZX0sImtleXMiOlt7ImlkIjoiOWViNDA1MGQtZTQ0Yi00ODAyLTkzMmUtMjdkNzUwODNlMjY2IiwiZW5jcnlwdGVkX2tleSI6ImxLM09qSExZVzI0Y3Iya3RSNzRmbnc9PSJ9XX19.FAbIiPxX8BHi9RwfzD7Yn-wugU19ghrkBFKsaCPrZmU'
        },
    }
}}
 style={styles.backgroundVideo}
/>
```

Comment: when I do as suggested above, get the following error in Android logcat with no video being played : -

`E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)`

Comment: @Sachin I have tried the same but cookies are not getting sent. Look at here please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680861/react-native-video-how-to-send-cloudfront-signed-cookies