# react-native-video: how to send CloudFront signed cookies

Tags: react-native, cookies, amazon-cloudfront, react-native-video, react-native-cookies

I am facing issues while sending CloudFront signed cookies in `react-native-video`

My video component look like this:

```
<Video
    source={{
        uri: uri,
        drm: {
            type: "widevine",
            licenseServer: 'https://drm-widevine-licensing.axtest.net/AcquireLicense',
            headers: {
                'Cookie': `CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=${cookies['CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id']};CloudFront-Signature=${cookies['CloudFront-Signature']};CloudFront-Policy=${cookies['CloudFront-Policy']}`
            },
        }
    }}
```

Also tried to add headers outside of drm (directly inside source) but still did not work

I have also tried this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363691/react-native-video-cookies) question but could not resolve it.

Comment: can you try by adding the same headers outside the drm?

Comment: I have tried that but still did not work for me

Comment: have you tried asking [this guy](https://chat.openai.com/chat) ?